# How to set the width of a JTextField at runtime?

Tags: java, swing, runtime, jtextfield

Can someone please help me how to set the width of a `JTextField` at runtime? I want my text field to be resized on runtime. It will ask the user for the length, then the input will change the width of the text field.

```
if(selectedComponent instanceof javax.swing.JTextField){
    javax.swing.JTextField txtField = (javax.swing.JTextField) selectedComponent;
    //txtField.setColumns(numInput); //tried this but it doesn't work
    //txtField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(numInput, txtField.getHeight())); //also this
    //txtField.setBounds(txtField.getX(), txtField.getY(), numInput, txtField.getHeight()); 
    //and this
    txtField.revalidate();
}
```

I am using `null` layout for this, since I'm on edit mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need to use [`jTextFieldObject.setColumns(int columnSize)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#setColumns%28int%29). This will let you increase it's size at runtime. The reason why you couldn't do it at your end is the `null` Layout. That is one of the main reasons why the use of `null Layout/Absolute Positioning` is discouraged.  Here is a small example for trying your hands on :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JTextFieldExample
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField tfield;
    private JButton button;
    private int size = 10;

    private ActionListener action = new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                frame, "Please Enter Columns : "
                                                , String.valueOf(++size));
            tfield.setColumns(Integer.parseInt(input));                 
            contentPane.revalidate();
            contentPane.repaint();
        }
    };

    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("JTextField Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);           

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));

        tfield = new JTextField();
        tfield.setColumns(size); 

        JButton  button = new JButton("INC Size");
        button.addActionListener(action);

        contentPane.add(tfield);
        contentPane.add(button);

        frame.getContentPane().add(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new JTextFieldExample().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For absolute positioning you need to call [`setSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize%28int,%20int%29) on the `JTextField` in order to attain the result, though you should always keep in mind the reason why this approach is discouraged, as given in the [Java Doc's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) first paragraph:

> Although it is possible to do without a layout manager, you should use a layout manager if at all possible. A layout manager makes it easier to adjust to look-and-feel-dependent component appearances, to different font sizes, to a container's changing size, and to different locales. Layout managers also can be reused easily by other containers, as well as other programs.

Comment: Oh.  :(  I really liked that answer before the edit that says..  *"For Absolute Positioning.."*  Eeek!  Let us not lead the newbie down the path to madness and monsters.  Oh well, +1 anyway.  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Thankx for pointing out my mistake, hence I made some changes in the said direction :-)

Answer (score 1):

I got the text field to resize just by using `setBounds`. Check out the following example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Resize extends JFrame{
    public JTextField jtf = new JTextField();

    public Resize(){
    //frame settings
    setTitle("Resizable JTextField");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(new Dimension(600,400));
    setResizable(false);

    //init and add text field to the frame
    add(jtf);
    jtf.setBounds(20,50,200,200);

    //button to change text field size
    JButton b = new JButton("Moar.");
    add(b);
    b.setBounds(20,20,b.getPreferredSize().width,b.getPreferredSize().height);
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            jtf.setBounds(20,50,jtf.getSize().width+10,jtf.getSize().height); //THIS IS WHERE THE RESIZING HAPPENS
        }
        });

    setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Resize inst = new Resize();
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 for null layout and manual sizing - whatever the problem, that's _not_ the solution

Comment: @kleopatra fair enough, though OP said they wanted to use `null` layout

Answer (score 0):

"Fun" little run-it-yourself solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTextField jTextField = new JTextField("Alice");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton grow = new JButton("DRINK ME");
    JButton shrink = new JButton("EAT ME");
    panel.add(jTextField);
    panel.add(grow);
    panel.add(shrink);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
    grow.addActionListener(l -> resize(frame, jTextField, 2));
    shrink.addActionListener(l -> resize(frame, jTextField, 0.5f));
}

private static void resize(JFrame frame, Component toResize, float factor) {
    System.out.println(toResize.getPreferredSize());
    toResize.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)(toResize.getPreferredSize().width * factor),
                                            (int)(toResize.getPreferredSize().height * factor)));
    toResize.setFont(toResize.getFont().deriveFont(toResize.getFont().getSize() * factor));
    frame.pack();
}
```

<sub>**Attention:** Please note that the consumption of too much cake can kill you.</sub>

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.